# install errors on astrisknow 6.12-64bit on vmware workstation 8

Tags: vmware, centos6.5

I'm using asterisk and trying to implement a test environment for testing asterisk functionalities on VM. I'm using VMware workstation 8 and trying to install AsteriskNOW 6.12-64 bit vi iso downloaded for following location.

http://www.asterisk.org/downloads/asterisknow

Now I'm stuck in the middle of:

> Installing VMware Tools,please wait...
>   mount : special device /dev/hda does not exist
>   mount : block device /dev/sr0 is write-protected, mounting read only

after that forever waiting.

This is taking too long and never ending. I tried to install several times and the result is same. I also noticed that the starting the install the following error is displayed, however it lets you to continue:

> Unsupported hardware detected.

This hardware (or a combination thereof ) is not supported by centos. {note that I'm using a typical VM in VMware}

I tried browsing google for a solution but couldn't find a solution. Please help and let me know if this is the best way to start with asterisk.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is trying to install VMWare tools into the VM. VMWare tools are optional and used for convinience only.

Try searching for a setting to disable this.

Comment: I tried that too ,and got  the same result. May be its the package comes with astriknow. I'm trying to install centos separately and compile the astrisk inside.

Comment: I got this solved. actually it was not stuck. system was  installing some of the binaries from the internet. It was to slow and after a long time the upgrade has been completed. Finally got my system working.

Comment: Were you able identify if this was due to astrisk binaries, VMWare tools binaries or OS?

Comment: The files were downloaded from the asterisk  repository usa, so i suspect there were asterisk libraries or binaries.